# Importing code from python project anywhere

Tags: python

I have a project that exists at a specific location:

```
~/repos/my_proj
```

And lets say it has a structure like the following:

```
my_proj/
   stuff1
   stuff2
```

And if I'm that directory I can include python code as one would think

```
from stuff1 import func1
from stuff2 import func2
```

Is there a way to "find" that directory and use it as a variable so I can include that code anywhere

Lets say I'm at `~/Docs/TestArea`

I'd like to be able to do

```
from my_proj_dir.stuff import func1
```

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder-in-python

Comment: Check the second answer in the link above, from joey.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways to approach this problem.  The better one is to set your [`PYTHONPATH` environment variable](https://docs.python.org/3.4/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) to include the folder `~/repos/my_proj`.

You could also from within Python you can manipulate the [`sys.path` list](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/sys.html#sys.path) that contains all the search paths where Python will be looking for modules -- before any import, you could just write

```
import sys
sys.path.append('~/repos/my_proj')
```

This is a bit uglier than setting `PYTHONPATH` because when you move your code to a different computer you would need to replicate the same folder structure.  However it allows the code to decide what paths to search after the program has already started, which can be useful sometimes.