# Unable to import class from another file in Python

Tags: python, unit-testing

I am trying to execute test suit by importing class from another file.
I have file list as below -
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0H4E.png)

I am using below -

```
import unittest
import HTMLTestRunner
from Enhancement.Exercise18_WriteExcel import TestEx18
from UnitTest.Exercise14_OrderFood import TestEx14

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # import sys;sys.argv = ['', 'Test.testName']
    unittest.main()
    # get all tests from Login and SignUp class
    tc1 = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(TestEx18)
    tc2 = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(TestEx14)
    # create a test suite combining tc1 and tc2
    test_suite = unittest.TestSuite([tc1, tc2])

    # run the suite
    unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=1).run(test_suite)

    #unittest.main(testRunner=HTMLTestRunner.HTMLTestRunner(output="demo/reports"))
```

But getting error -
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vT2pj.png)

Kindly advise how can I resolve this issue.

Comment: Try to put the error directly into your message, thanks !  :)

Answer (score 0):

Run the same command from /path/to/Selenium_Practice/ folder (and not /path/to/Selenium_Practice/Reporting/ folder)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the answer found here ==> https://stackoverflow.com/a/28224295/16879293

basically, you have 2 options, one would be to add your Enhancement to the PYTHONPATH, or you can simply add to your code :

```
import sys
sys.append("..")
```